# creating a hierarchical dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am working on eCommerce site in asp.net 3.5.in that i have to create categories.The categories is Stored as hierarchical order based on parent Id.Because the level can increase.

my problem is in add/Edit Categories page.in that categories has to display in hierarchy.

i was searching in Google for any help to create a hierarchical drop down list in asp.net.but i didn't get it.instead i found http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm.

i am confused if i used the list instead of dropdownlist.
how can i get the value of selected item in code behind while saving.and how to select the item on category edit.

please help to sort out this.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to use recursion once I created it you can check my code. You can modify according to your requirement.

```
public void FillDDLOfParentCat()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dal.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM Category_Master WHERE Parent='0' ORDER BY Name");
            ddl_category.Items.Add("--Select category--");
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    ListItem li = new ListItem(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["PK_ID"].ToString());
                    ddl_category.Items.Add(li);
                    PrintChild(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["PK_ID"].ToString()), "----");
                }
            }


        }
        public void PrintChild(int pk_id, string Space)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dal.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM Category_Master WHERE Parent='" + pk_id + "' ORDER BY Name");

            string sp = new string(Space.ToCharArray());
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    ListItem li = new ListItem(sp + dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["PK_ID"].ToString());
                    ddl_category.Items.Add(li);


                    PrintChild(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["PK_ID"].ToString()), "----" + sp);

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is an option for you, but the RadComboBox from Telerik is extremely flexible. Here's an example where I embedded a tree view in a RadComboBox:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Skin="Sunset" AutoPostBack="true" Width="500" Font-Size="12px" Font-Names="Verdana" OnClientDropDownOpened="onDropDownOpened">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="padding:0px 0px 5px 5px;">
            <telerik:RadTreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Skin="Sunset" Font-Size="12px" Font-Names="Verdana" OnNodeClick="TreeView1_NodeClick" PersistLoadOnDemandNodes="true" ShowLineImages="true" OnClientNodeClicking="onTreeNodeClicking" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```